# ASP.NET Application isn't reaching WCF Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf

The set up I have on my local machine works fine, but when I push it to the server I encounter an issue. All my calls work on the server until I call this certain method in the Reference.cs file.

```
public DataResults GetData(DataRequest request) {
        return base.Channel.GetData(request);
    }
```

Then nothing happens after this is called, it just sits there. No exception is being thrown or anything.

I had my logger code log points on each method, it gets to this method, but never gets to the WCF method. But all the other WCF method except for 2 of them. And the two works when I run it on my local machine.

The WCF method is set up like this:

The interface has:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [FaultContract(typeof(Domain.Fault.SystemFault))]
    [FaultContract(typeof(Domain.Fault.BusinessFault))]
    DataResults GetData(DataRequest request);
```

and the actual method:

```
public DataResults GetData(DataRequest request)
    {
        try
        {
            Logger.LogInformation("Got to service");
            DataResults dr=CallDB(request);
            return dr;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw this.getFaultExceptionComplete("GetData failed");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you get a response from *any* methods on the web service?

Comment: have you enabled tracing for your WCF service? When you get silent errors in WCF, that's usually the first place I look.

Comment: @Ek0nomik: All other methods work except for 2 of them. And when I use a WCFClientTool to test the WCF service, all the methods work.

Comment: @Er0x: I do have tracing enabled, but I'm not sure how to read the SVCLog files...

Comment: can you add the code for DataResults and CallDB()?

Comment: I made that class and CallDB() up. Neither of those having anything to do with the problem. The same code works fine when running on my local machine.

Comment: I note that you ignore the exception you caught. That may not be the source of _this_ problem, but it _will_ be the source of some future problem. Be certain to log that exception or else allow it to propagate.